# An excel formula using IS BLANK and IS NOT BLANK based on two columns

Tags: excel, xls, formulas

I need to calc the time between two dates. If column V is blank, then look at column X; now  return the difference btw the returned value (either X or V)  and  the date in  column S.

Comment: What is the maximum difference that you expect to have?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
=IF(ISBLANK(V2),S2-X2,S2-V2)
```

In words: If cell V2 is blank, calculate S2 minus X2, otherwise calculate S2 minus V2.

Adjust to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

For row 1, you could use

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK(V1),V1=""),X1-S1,V1-S1)
```

It is extremely important to note that **blank** and an **empty string** behave differently. This shows up once and again, and it is a source of quite a bit of trouble. Any formula or code should account for this, according to the demands of the task.

In addition, you have to **select an appropriate number format**. For instance, use *Custom*, and in *Type* use **dd"d" hh:mm**.